# Problem decoding json from input args with Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I'm trying to write a Haskell program that expects Json string provided as input. Expected Json is a list of `Person` objects. I want to handle a case when user did not provide input by defaulting to Json of empty list. 
It seems like I'm running into type conversion issue between ByteString and String. I do have `OverloadedStrings` turned on but it doesn't seem to help here. Here's the simplified code.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import GHC.Generics
import System.Environment
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe, listToMaybe)
import Data.Text (Text)

data Person = Person { pName :: Text, pAge :: Int } deriving (Show, 
Generic)
instance ToJSON Person
instance FromJSON Person

main :: IO (Maybe [Person])
main = do
  args <- getArgs
  arg1 <- pure $ (fromMaybe "[]" (listToMaybe args))
  -- let arg1 = "[{\"pName\": \"James\", \"pAge\": 30}]"
  return $ decode arg1 :: IO (Maybe [Person])
```

Error I'm getting is:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’
                 with ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
  Expected type: Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
    Actual type: String
• In the first argument of ‘decode’, namely ‘arg1’
  In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘decode arg1’
  In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      return $ decode arg1 :: IO (Maybe [Person])
```

If I uncomment `let arg1` to simulate what arg1 should be, then code compiles.

Comment: `arg1 <- pure $ ...` can be written as `let arg1 = ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getArgs` returns a `[String]`, not a `[ByteString]`. `decode` really wants a `ByteString` as input.

`OverloadedStrings` doesn't help with that; it only affects string literals in your code, not external inputs. That's why the version with the hardcoded argument (`let arg1 = "[{\"pName\": \"James\", \"pAge\": 30}]"`) works: `arg1` automatically becomes a `ByteString` to make `decode arg1` work, but `getArgs` has an incompatible type.

One possible fix would be to encode the command line strings to bytes somehow, but there seems to be [an easier alternative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-2.7.2.2/docs/System-Posix-Env-ByteString.html#v:getArgs):

```
import System.Posix.Env.ByteString (getArgs)
```

which gives you a

```
getArgs :: IO [ByteString]
```

(I haven't actually tested this code; you may also have to use `decodeStrict` instead of `decode`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why is it so challenging to do these kind of conversions in Haskell?... I tried what you suggested, now I'm getting this error `Couldn't match expected type ‘Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString’
                  with actual type ‘Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString’`

Comment: "Why is it so hard" is in part because you don't know how and in part because the conversions are provided by libraries instead of built into the language.  If you know how then it becomes easy.  You can `pack` strings of 8 bit characters into bytestrings.  You can encode them using UTF8 (or other encodings).  Or one of many other solutions.